# There are no field structures on $\mathbb{R}^3$, but what of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\geq 4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Has it been proved that there do not exist nice field structures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\geq 4$?

The quaternions $\mathbb{H}$ fail due to lack of commutativity and the bicomplex numbers $\mathbb{C}\oplus \mathbb{C}$ fail due to non-zero non-invertible elements.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra#Associative_division_algebras

Comment: As you want to keep commutativity everything follows from the fact that $\Bbb{C}$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: There do exist field structures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n$ since there are bijections between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$ and a bunch of other fields. You'd need to be more specific as to what you want that structure to satisfy.

Comment: From the Wiki - "In fact, every finite-dimensional real commutative division algebra is either 1- or 2-dimensional. "

I do not believe that is correct as long as you don't require associativity or distributivity which makes me doubt the rest of the Wiki.
Tradition math proofs tend to ignore modern programmed math tools such as conditionals.

Comment: The proof of the Frobenius theorem given at http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras) is very elementary; it assumes only knowledge of linear algebra. If you do not understand the proof you should state which part is unclear.

Comment: The proof appears to rely on the Q(z:x) polynomial form which is restricted essentially to 2D.
But once one goes past 2 dimensions one must add something new other than simply (x-z)(x-conj(z)) because conj(z) is no longer a singular option - it makes more sense that something like (x-za)(x-zb)(x-zc) should be included for 3 dimensions and so on.

Comment: @Makin'MagicFractals: this is just the fact that all roots of a polynomial with real coefficients are real or come in pairs of conjugate complex numbers. Are you familiar with this fact? It is a good exercise to prove yourself. The key that you are missing is that elements of your division algebra define linear transformations of a real vector space, the underlying vector space of the algebra.

Comment: Fine - but in that Q equation, what about adding:
(x-a-bi-cj)(x+a+bi-cj)(x-a-bi+cj)(x+a+bi+cj)
Which reduces to:
xxxx-2xxaa+2xxbb-2aabb+aaaa+bbbb-cccc
assuming ii=jj=-1

Comment: What are i and j? I was talking about complex numbers and you are talking about?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably referring to the [Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra) that the only associative division algebras that are finite-dimensional as vector spaces over the reals are up to isomorphism the reals themselves, the complex numbers, and the quaternions. If commutativity is added only $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ remain.

However, it is essential that we require a division algebra or a field to inherit the vector space (or at least the additive group) structure of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Without that we can put a field structure on any $\mathbb{R}^n$ by mapping it bijectively onto $\mathbb{R}$, and it doesn't even make sense to talk about dimension.